# Issue installing solidus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

Quite new to rails development, i'm having an issue when trying to install the Solidus Gem. It worked fine days ago when i first tried it, but since i've installed postgresql and now this is what happens:

- I type rails new myshop (works fine with rails 5.0)
- Add the gems to my gemfile
- bundle install
- bundle update

But then, following the solidus installation guide (https://github.com/solidusio/solidus) when i type "bundle exec rails g spree:install", nothing happens. My terminal seems to freeze out. No errors showing, nothing. The prompt is waiting..

[Image of the prompt freezing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcRuK.png)

Comment: can you provide a picture or something of what's happening? Have you tried just `rails g spree:install`

Comment: I've juste edited the post to add the image. I've tried rails g spree:install, same problem!